# chrome storage sync not syncing across multiple devices

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am using `chrome.storage.sync` to save data to a users google account. Whenever I save my data, I am checking my other computer to see if the data is saved across my google account. What I find is that my data is not saved across my account.

Could this be happening because I am loading my extension in `Load Unpacked`? Just to be clear, on my published extension, the `chrome.storage.sync` feature is working

`index.js`

```js
// Save item in storage sync
function storeItems(item, key) {
chrome.storage.sync.set({key : item})
}

// get items from storage sync.
function getItems(key) {
 chrome.storage.sync.get([key], (result) => {
      return result.key
}) 
}
```

So I use `storeItems()` in computer 1, I expect computer 2 should `getItems()` successfully

From checking the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/sync) it should be saving across devices as long as i am in the same google account.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please provide us a piece of code you're using ? It's the be way to help us answer you :)

Comment: Hey there! I just updated my answer

Comment: Hello. The syntax you're using is not suitable here : `chrome.storage.sync.get([key], (result) {` : missing `function` word before `(result)`. Please track such errors and provide us your manifest file and an error free code sample :) BTW, what do you get for the value ? An `undefined` error, an empty value ?

Comment: Apologies for the typo, I had forgotten to add the arrow to my description

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue, `chrome.storage.sync` isn't work as the documentation describes.